# Index Route under another Index route

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I am building a UI that has several layers of nested routes. I came to a scenario where I want to nest something under an implicit indexroute. Now I have to define that index route and the nesting beneath, or not?

Here is a screenshot what I am trying to achieve:
[image: Layout]

My router that is trying to implement this:

```
  this.resource('usergroup', { path: '/tippspiele/:usergroup_id' }, function(){
      this.resource('usergroup.index', { path: '/' },function(){

      });
      this.route('table');
  });
```

Unfortunately the UsergroupIndexIndex template is not rendered by default. And within the view tree I can't see it either.

This is how this setup looks in ember inspector:
[image: Ember Inspector screenshot]

I also have added a manual Link in order to check if I can link to the indexIndex but the outlet for the subtemplate stays empty.

Comment: Is there any reason you have to use the 'index' route? Why not just name it something else (that doesn't carry implicit functionality)? You can always have the 'index' redirect if you need. Also, I don't think `usergroup.index` is doing what you think. You should view the route names with `Ember.keys(App.Router.router.recognizer.names)` to make sure things are working the way you expect.

Comment: Cannot read property 'recognizer' of null  <-- when checking the route names. I want to use index in order to render the child templates when accessing the usergroup route. So when somebody goes to the "usergroup" route, the usergroupindex and usergroupindexindex should be rendered by default into the according child templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template name should be given as follows:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="usergroup/index/index">
    // template content
</script>
```

This is the corresponding route:

```
App.UsergroupIndexIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    // return the model
    return [];
  }
});
```

Comment: I have defined a template and an route, but the template is not being rendered. Its not even in the view tree.

Comment: ok thanks, that did the trick, i was thinking the templatename would be usergroup/index.index .. which wasnt working.